# How do I read the text of a resource txt file and put it into a TextBox in C# .net 4.0 WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How do I read the text of a resource txt file and put it into a TextBox in C# .net 4.0 WPF?
I have a TextBox in my form and a TXT file in my resources folder,
how do I put the text from the TXT file (including the line breaks, double spaces, etc) into the TextBox?

Please simplify the code for me because I'm a beginner in C#...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference reading file in WinForms or in WPF.
Simply add to you window TextBox and load file via System.IO.File class.

Example :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="tb" Margin="4"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Load file" x:Name="btnLoad" Click="btnLoad_Click" Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4"/>

</Grid>
```

and code behavior :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tb.Text = File.ReadAllText(@"*path to file*");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I define the path as a resource (from the Resources folder) ?
Thanks!!

Comment: simply, specify absolute/relative path to your file. For example, File.ReadAllText(@"../../Resources/FILE_NAME").

Comment: I'll try it soon - if it works, I'll just mark your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to provide code, there is already a very simple WPF Example for this exact problem, found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx).

And btw, don't ask on SO for "Hey could you guys solve that for me!" you should ask questions more like "Hey i tried this, and that. Why didn't this work, what is wrong with that. I also read somewhere that this is considered bad, why exactly?".
Show that you put work already into the problem, this will greatly increase the amount of time and effort people are willingly to put into your problem.

Comment: But it would be a lie, I didn't come to trying it because I'm re-writing a program of mine from VB to C#, and why won't people do some work for me when that program is a free tool for Cinema 4D? :)